# TextBox does not Update when Text is the same

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

I have a `TextBox`. The `TextBox` is binded to a Property. The Property will be set each time I type a character into the Box. That works perfect!

Now I want to remove invalid characters when they are typed in.

For example: The user typed `@` and `@` is not allowed so it will be removed (something like `string.replace("@", "");`.

That also works fine. The old Text is, lets say "6378fj". Now someone types `@`. The new Text, `6378@fj`, will be sent to the Property, the `@` will be removed (now its `6378fj`) and `OnPropertyChanged` will be fired.

Now the TextBox gets the new Value from the Property, but it's now the same value as before. And the `@`still remains in The TextBox. It's a bit strange, ans it only works when the Validated Text is the same as the original Text.

Is there a way to let the TextBox update itself? I hope you know what I mean, I'm not a native English speaker. Thanks.

Comment: could you share some code please?

Comment: Can you provide some source code? Do you set your internal variable to the corrected value before firing OnPropertyChanged? Have you considered using a validator?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're replacing the character in the setter of the property? If the property is being updated by the binding, the `PropertyChanged` event for that property is ignored. You need to raise the event after the binding has finished updating the property. An easy way to do that is to use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => OnPropertyChanged("TheProperty")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to perform validation on the text entered into the `TextBox` by handling the [`PreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event. This will allow you to check the new text before it is committed to the `TextBox`. If you wish to prevent the edit, you can use `e.Handled = true` on the [`TextCompositionEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.aspx) passed into the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but you say you are doing `string.Replace("@","")`.  You are remembering to assign the result back to your original string, aren't you?  I know it is an obvious question, but I have seen it too many times to not mention it here. :)

ie. `myString = myString.Replace("@","");`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want deny input of symbols like '@'? I think it'll be easier than searching these symbols and its deleting...

In this case you can use `PreviewTextInput` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "Hello";
String str2 = "Hello";
bool ch = str1 == str2;
```